# c++11 shared_ptr + Boost::Serialization

Tags: c++, serialization, boost, shared-ptr

I am in need of a Boost::Serialization specialization for std::shared_ptr.

I am writing a program that sends objects over Boost::Asio and many of those objects use shared_ptrs internally. Using a workaround to only serialize the objects they are referring to is quite uncomfortable.

I have been trying to make my own, looking at the implementation provided for Boost::shared_ptr but I lack the understanding of how those objects should be handled.

Changing the namespaces in Boost::shared_ptr serialization made it possible to serialize the pointer but deserialization doesn't work for me.

As a last resort, I could(and maybe should) switch over to using std::unique_ptrs for my objects, because, at the moment, it seems they own them, but that would lead me to the same problem, only with unique_ptr.

Comment: You definitely should prefer std::unique_ptr instead of std::shared_ptr wherever applicable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do this but it seems to work.

Changed the namespace and added this load method to shared_ptr specialization header copied from Boost::shared_ptr specialization:

```
template<class Archive, class T>
inline void load(
    Archive & ar,
    std::shared_ptr< T > &t,
    const unsigned int /* file_version */
){
    T * t_ptr;
    ar >> boost::serialization::make_nvp("px", t_ptr);
    t = std::shared_ptr<T>(t_ptr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You say that you use `std::shared_ptr` internally. So why you don't use `boost::shared_ptr` in place of it, it is completely supported by `boost::serialization` and has same functionality of `std::shared_ptr`?

Comment: The main argument for me has been to stick with standard implementations as much as possible, only using other libraries for stuff the c++ standard didn't have.

If possible, I would leave this as a last resort solution.

Comment: You are using `boost` for serialization, so your program is compatible with a compiler that support it!! so why you don't want to use `boost::shared_ptr` that is the source of `std::shared_ptr`. it is as standard as `std::shared_ptr` and even support more platforms and compilers, so what is the problem in using it??

Comment: @BigBoss I understand your argument, but *"it is as standard as `std::shared_ptr`"* - No, it isn't.

Comment: Why you say it isn't? Remember you already include the `boost`, `std` is just another library that implemented on all compilers with proper support for standard, so what is `boost`? isn't it a library with same purpose that its compatibility with all platforms are maintained by a large group of programmers? many standards come from `boost`(like `shared_ptr` itself!! But if you want to use `std::` before `shared_ptr` that is another discussion

Comment: Boost's implementations are slightly different and therefore nonstandard.

Please remember that this is not the place to discuss this, because the discussion is not relevant to the topic.

Comment: @BigBoss In practice (and also disregarding any possible incompatibilities) you might be right with your argumentation and I understand it (like already said), but still you cannot just say it is as standard as `std::shared_ptr`, because not `boost::shared_ptr` is part of the C++ programming language standard, but `std::shared_ptr`. No matter how theoretical this fact may seem to you (or how irrelevant it is in this particular context), it is a hard fact. (And as a side note, when addressing people in comments try to use the @-syntax, otherwise they won't get notified about your response.)

Comment: @BigBoss And in the same way the two implementations of `shared_ptr` may be different. I admit that I don't know if they are different, and I myself assume they aren't. But still there is no guarantee that they are always the same, just because they were copied/inspired by each other once upon a time.

Comment: @Christian Rau It seems to me their implementations are different since the serialization code didn't work by just changing the namespace.

Comment: @ChristianRau, @jt234 I never said they are identical, i say they are same for your usage, since you already using `boost`. Some parts of standard are related to the compiler and can't supported without proper support from compiler, but other parts are just libraries (like `std::string` or `std::shared_ptr`). so as long as you have that library available on all platforms that you need what make them different from standard? namespace `std`? and of course it never work with changing namespace, if you write a plugin for `std::string` based on GCC and move it to MSVC, it work?

Comment: If you rely on public interface of `std::string` in GCC then it should work in MSVC, but if you call any implementation dependent feature of GCC then it never work with MSVC, `boost::serialization` use some implementation dependent part of `boost::shared_ptr` so it is wise to think it never work with `std::shared_ptr`